# Converting python binary to pem format

Tags: python-3.x, base64

From an ldap directory I am getting a binary certificate representation. I would like to write a pem file from it:

What I am currently doing (it works) is:

- I encode the crt in `base64`
- Strip off all newlines (there are newlines every 76 chars)
- split ans join it into chunks of 64 chars

```
    chunk_size = 64
    crt_string = base64_encode(crt)[0].decode("ascii").replace("\n",'')
    chunked = '\n'.join(crt_string[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(crt_string), chunk_size))
    return f"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n{chunked}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
```

It all seems very clumsy to me.

**Is there a utility function that I overlook to write `pem` like base64 strings?

Answer (score 0):

I think your version is ok.
However, found this one

```
import ssl

pem_cert = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(crt)
```

According to this [docs](https://pythontic.com/ssl/ssl-module/der_cert_to_pem_cert)